# How do I make a jar file that opens a webpage?

Tags: java

class file that opens your default web browser to a webpage and I wanted to know how do I make it in to a jar file that when dubble clicked it will open up the web page.

Here is the code for the .class file.

```
public class UpdateChecker {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
         //Set your page url in this string.
         String url = "//www.curseforge.com/projects/69994/";
         java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
       }
       catch (java.io.IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Didn't know you wrote Java in .class files.

Comment: You could just create a shortcut on the desktop with the URI as the target and skip Java altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a java-archive by using `jar` command.

First create a manifest file (named "manifest.txt") with the following content:

```
Main-Class: UpdateChecker
```

**Note**: End this file with an empty line and save this in same directory as your .class file. Then in command prompt use the following command to create the Jar:

```
jar cvfm updatechecker.jar manifest.txt UpdateChecker.class
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the line `Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass` to the MANIFEST.MF file inside the META-INF folder of your jar file. And change the package and class name to your names of course.
See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html for details.